# Sencha Touch - event listener for NestedList back button?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, listeners, event-listener

Sencha Touch 1.1.1 --

Is there a way to set up a listener to listen for click events on the Back button of a NestedList? I can only find examples of how to set up for clicks on the 'body' or 'el' element. How would you be more specific and target the NestedList's back button?

Many Thanks

Code so far

```
MyTest.views.Justacard = Ext.extend(Ext.NestedList, {
    title: "The Title",
    ...
    listeners: {
        click: {
            element: 'el', // ANYTHING HERE TO TARGET THE BACK BUTTON?
            fn: function(){
                // do action                
            }
        }
    }   
});
Ext.reg('justacard', MyTest.views.Justacard);
```

On a side note: because the NestedList component adds the back button automatically, there's no opportuity to configure it and add a handler (I think).

PS: adding the following code (below title: for example) allows me to respond to the Back button clicks - however, it also removes all the normal Back button functionality and the NestedList no longer slides back to the parent list.

```
    onBackTap: function() {
        alert('boo');
    }
```

Turning into a proper 'lumpy carpet' scenario ; )

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
MyTest.views.Justacard = Ext.extend(Ext.NestedList, {
    title: "The Title",
    ...
    listeners: {
        back: function() {
            alert('back?');
        }
    }   
});
```

or

```
onBackTap: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    alert('boo');
}
```

P.S. Sorry, I didn't test this (just looked at sources)